# Loading saved model (Bidirectional LSTM) in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm

I trained and saved a Bidirectional LSTM model in Keras successfully with:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(N_HIDDEN_NEURONS,
                        return_sequences=True,
                        activation="tanh",
                        input_shape=(SEGMENT_TIME_SIZE, N_FEATURES))))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(N_HIDDEN_NEURONS)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(N_CLASSES, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
          epochs=N_EPOCHS,
          validation_data=[X_test, y_test])

model.save('model_keras/model.h5')
```

However, when I want to load it with:

```
model = load_model('model_keras/model.h5')
```

I get an error:

> ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 3 layers
>   into a model with 0 layers.

I also tried different methods like saving and loading model architecture and weights separately but none of them worked for me. Also, previously, when I was using normal (unidirectional) LSTMs, loading the model worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure your model is constructed without errors? The `input_shape=(SEGMENT_TIME_SIZE, N_FEATURES)` argument should be an argument of `Bidirectional` layer not the `LSTM`. What is your Keras version?

Comment: @today I'm pretty sure it's an argument of the LSTM layer

Comment: @Primusa It is strange. It gives me an error on Keras 2.1.3.

Comment: Let me test it, I'll get back to you if it's just me being stupid :P

Comment: This seems like a bug inside keras

Comment: @TomaszBartkowiak Please post the output of this as well: `import keras; print(keras.__version__)`.

Comment: @today, i'm running keras version 2.2.0, this code throws an error for me when loading the saved model. Does the same happen for you? https://pastebin.com/iKCXZVxG

Comment: @Primusa For me, as I said before, it complains of the `input_shape`, specifically: `ValueError: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an 'input_shape' or 'batch_input_shape' argument.` Probably it is because of my Keras version (i.e. 2.1.3) is older than yours.

Comment: Could you try updating keras, the version I am using is more recent. Unless there is a way to save on 2.1.3 in which case I should probably downgrade

Comment: @Primusa After upgrading to 2.2.0 it gives me the same error that the OP got.

Comment: @today I'm using Keras 2.2.0

Comment: @today what If you run your code with
```model.fit(np.random.rand(10, SEGMENT_TIME_SIZE, N_FEATURES), np.random.randn(10, N_CLASSES),
          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
          epochs=N_EPOCHS,
          validation_data=[np.random.rand(2, SEGMENT_TIME_SIZE, N_FEATURES), np.random.randn(2, N_CLASSES)])```
It works for me.

Comment: I'm quite sure `input_shape` parameter should be in `Bidirectional`. At least, on both Keras 2.1.5 and 2.2.0, if `input_shape` is defined is `Bidirectional`, I can save and load the model without error!

Comment: @mpariente @today You were right guys. `input_shape` is an argument of `Bidirectional`, not `LSTM`, see [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [@mpariente](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7248396/mpariente) and [@today](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2099607/today), the `input_shape` is an argument of Bidirectional, not LSTM, see [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#bidirectional).  My solution:

```
# Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(N_HIDDEN_NEURONS,
                             return_sequences=True,
                             activation="tanh"), 
                        input_shape=(SEGMENT_TIME_SIZE, N_FEATURES)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(N_HIDDEN_NEURONS)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(N_CLASSES, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
          epochs=N_EPOCHS,
          validation_data=[X_test, y_test])

model.save('model_keras/model.h5')
```

and then, to load, simply do:

```
model = load_model('model_keras/model.h5')
```